# Back button jquery to previous page after current page has been reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I need a way to go back to a previous page after the current page has been reloaded.

At the moment if I use my simple history -1 on the page that has been reloaded in jQuery it will send me back to the same (reloaded)page as is only expected.

Is there a way to identify that the page is the same page and therefore ignore it as a relevant option to go back to?

Here is the code I am using at the moment:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('a.back-link').click(function(){
    parent.history.back();
    return false;
   });
  });
```

Thanks,

Aidan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use document.referrer to get the address of the page that originally referred you to your current page (location.reload() should not affect the referrer variable)

```
location.href = document.referrer;
```

A working example can be found here http://iamdevelop.in/referrer

Comment: I think this would work best however would I have to refer to this page for the document.referrer to work as in the example with: onclick="location.href =

Comment: Nope, hyperlinks will work too, as long as the page was linked to from another page, the original page's URL should be in the document.referrer variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using your `history.go(-1)`, you can simply specify a different number to go a different number of pages.

Try using:

```
window.history.go(-2);
```

This should then skip that 1 back page which is the same and go back to the page before that.

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_go.asp)

Comment: I understand that but to me it was for the more practical solution